# Elasticsearch equivalent to Map-Reduce

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the equivalent of map-reduce in ElasticSearch when the processing is too much for the client-side?
Is there something like "streaming" so the client can reduce data to output as it comes in?

Assume I need to do a join, or complex filtering at client side, the type that might not fit in memory without some map-reduce scheme.
I don't mind waiting a long time for the response, but I dont want to crush the machine (client and/or server).

How should I go about this?

Example, mappings:

```
{"book":{"properties":{
                       "title":{"type":"string", "index":"analyzed"},
                       "author":{"type":"string", "index":"analyzed"},
}

{"character":{"properties":{
                       "book_id":{"type":"string", "index":"not_analyzed"},
                       "name":{"type":"string", "index":"analyzed"},
                       "age":{"type":"integer"},
                       "catch-phrase":{"type":"string", "index":"analyzed"},
}
```

Say I want to find all the books that have at least M characters that have a catch phrase no longer than N (where N is a parameter supplied at client side)

so it would be `get_books_with_short_phrases(M,N)`

I could of course add fields such as "phrase-length" to the "character" type, but let's assume the processing on "catch-phrase" might be changing all the time.

I'd like to stream the "characters" and "books" to the client, go over each client and output a key-value of `<book>-<character,len(phrase)>` then reduce it further to `<book>-<num_of_chars_with_short_phrase>`

If I load all documents into the client memory, that might be a disaster. If the client processes each book and reduces it to a k,v it might be better.

Am I going wrong about it?

Is the solution running scripts on the server somehow, so it performs the map-reduce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

afaik you can't do streaming with ES.

As I'm sure you know it's best to get into a different mindset in which 'joins' do not exist. Instead denormalize and try to cover your usecase with 1 query to ES of course this doesn't always work.

In the above case however, I invite you to take a look at the script-filter, which allows complex computations (akin to sql stored procedures) which allow query-time parameters.

I'm pretty confident this should give you the tools to do the query in 1 go on the server, although I only didn't look deep into it.

http://www.elastic.co/guide/reference/query-dsl/script-filter/
http://www.elastic.co/guide/reference/modules/scripting/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, data should probably be denormalized so you have everything in one document.

Then I would look at [scripted metrics](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html), which allows you to use either in-query groovy scripts or native Java scripts to perform a map/reduce like distributed processing on the Elasticsearch nodes themselves where you only return the resulting reduced values. See e.g. [this example](https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-native-script-example/tree/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/examples/nativescript/script/stockaggs) for a sample Java implementation.